# even up textboxes in form in HTML

Tags: html, css

I am creating a form and I put `input`next to `textboxes`.What I want is to even up all textboxes so they start from the same position (like in the table). I tried to use flex but it only expanded the width of textboxes but I don't want to change them. All I want is that all `<textarea class="autofit" required pattern="^abc$" placeholder="Nie dotyczy" ></textarea><br/>` will start from the same position. Of course, 1 textbox and input should be in 1 line.

Moreover, in the `<label for="kom">Test 2</label>` I want textbox to be visible only if user will select *Others:* so if user select 1, 2 ,3 the textbox should disappear, if *Others:* the textbox appears.

```css
form {
  font: 15px Arial, sans-serif;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

input[type=text],
select {
  width: auto;
  padding: 8px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  align-self: center;
}

label {
  padding: 12px 12px 12px 0;
  min-width: 1.2rem;
  width: 20%;
  max-width: 50rem;
  min-height: 1.2em;
  height: 1.2em;
}

fieldset {
  border: none;
}

textarea {
  min-width: 1.2rem;
  width: 20%;
  max-width: 50rem;
  resize: none;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  min-height: 1.2em;
  height: 1.2em;
  padding: 3px;
  max-height: 100%;
  align-self: center;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<form class="form">
  <label for="formName">Name</label>
  <textarea class="autofit" required pattern="^abc$" placeholder="Put name here"></textarea><br/>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="formtype">Test 1</label>
    <select id="type">
  <option value="">Test 1</option>
  <option value="1">Test 2</option>
</select>
  </div><br/>

  <div class="content" data-response="op1">
    <fieldset class="komunikacyjne">
      <label>Header</label><br/>

      <label for="kom">Test 2</label>
      <select id="kom" required>
          <option value="k1">Option 1</option>
          <option value="k2">Option 2</option>
          <option value="k3">Option 3</option>
          <option value="k4">Others:</option>
          <textarea class="autofit" required pattern="^abc$" placeholder="Nie dotyczy" ></textarea><br/>
      </select><br/>

      <input type="checkbox" required name="komunik" /> 11111111
      <textarea class="autofit" required pattern="^abc$" placeholder="Nie dotyczy"></textarea><br/>
      <input type="checkbox" required name="komunik" /> 222
      <textarea class="autofit" required pattern="^abc$" placeholder="Nie dotyczy"></textarea><br/>
      <input type="checkbox" required name="komunik" />3
      <textarea class="autofit" required pattern="^abc$" placeholder="Nie dotyczy"></textarea><br/>
      <input type="checkbox" required name="komunik" /> 444
      <textarea class="autofit" required pattern="^abc$" placeholder="Nie dotyczy"></textarea><br/>
      <input type="checkbox" required name="komunik" /> 555555
      <textarea class="autofit" required pattern="^abc$" placeholder="Nie dotyczy"></textarea><br/>
      <input type="checkbox" required name="komunik" /> 6
      <textarea class="autofit" required pattern="^abc$" placeholder="Nie dotyczy"></textarea><br/>
      <input type="checkbox" required name="komunik" /> 777777777
      <textarea class="autofit" required pattern="^abc$" placeholder="Nie dotyczy"></textarea><br/>
      <input type="checkbox" required name="majat" /> 8
      <textarea class="autofit" required pattern="^abc$" placeholder="Nie dotyczy"></textarea><br/>
    </fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do it. I put `<label>` before `input` starting tag and `</label>` after `input` ending tag.Please see the updated code below:

```css
input[type=text], select {
    padding: 8px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    align-self: center;
  }
label {

  display: inline-block;
  min-width:100px;
  width:20%;
  max-width:100rem;
  min-height:1.2em;
  height:1.2em;
}
```

```html
<label><input type="checkbox" required name="komunik" />test 11111111</label>
<textarea class="autofit" required pattern="^abc$" placeholder="Nie dotyczy"></textarea><br/>
<label><input type="checkbox" required name="komunik" /> test 2</label>
<textarea class="autofit" required pattern="^abc$" placeholder="Nie dotyczy"></textarea><br/>
<label><input type="checkbox" required name="komunik" /> test 3</label>
<textarea class="autofit" required pattern="^abc$" placeholder="Nie dotyczy"></textarea><br/>
<label><input type="checkbox" required name="komunik" /> test 4444444</label>
<textarea class="autofit" required pattern="^abc$" placeholder="Nie dotyczy"></textarea><br/>
<label><input type="checkbox" required name="komunik" /> test 5</label>
<textarea class="autofit" required pattern="^abc$" placeholder="Nie dotyczy"></textarea><br/>
<label><input type="checkbox" required name="komunik" /> test 6666666</label>
<textarea class="autofit" required pattern="^abc$" placeholder="Nie dotyczy"></textarea><br/>
<label><input type="checkbox" required name="komunik" /> test 7</label>
<textarea class="autofit" required pattern="^abc$" placeholder="Nie dotyczy"></textarea><br/>
<label><input type="checkbox" required name="majat" /> test 8</label>
<textarea class="autofit" required pattern="^abc$" placeholder="Nie dotyczy"></textarea><br/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I would try to use a table in your case.
See the example below. (No styling included)
The checkbox is a bit right by default because its size does not fit to its visual borders.

```html
<form>
  <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Name</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="one" /></td>
        <tr/>
        <tr>
          <td>VeryLongInputName</td>
          <td><input type="checkbox" name="two" /></td>
        <tr/>
        <tr>
          <td>Short</td>
          <td><textarea name="three"></textarea></td>
        <tr/>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: I thought about this solution but I have 11 fieldsets in total with more than 100 inputs and textboxes. It would take long time to change everything in HTML. Each input type is checkbox and each textbox has class named "autofit".I assume that there is a way to style it within CSS.

Comment: well you could set a static length for your input labels... then you would have all inputs in a column